# Find out the frequency that someone is using my code (bash or python)

Tags: python, bash, monitoring, event-tracking

Working in academia, one of the most important things for us when applying for research funding is to be able to evidence how other people benefit from your work.

Using number of downloads is a poor metric for this. It would be much better if we could show how frequently the code is used (i.e. 10 people using something daily is better than 100 downloading but never using).

Is there a way to do this using bash or python scripts? My idea so far has been around using wget or curl pointed at a url (used only for this) which has google analytics attached to it. This way we could monitor number of executions and location (this info would be sufficient).

I'm not quite sure how it would be implemented. Any suggestions?

NOTE: the code will be open source, so they could see what we're doing, we would include an explanation why it's useful for grants (and therefore their benefit), have a switch for them to disable this feature if needs be and the script would still run if there was no internet connection.

Comment: I think your idea of `GET`ting a specific URL (with your software version as an argument) would be quite easy and defensible. You can infer a *little* bit of identity from your web server logs (e.g., sender's apparent ip address), though in reality I think that's just giving you an iota. Your point about *"see what we're doing"* is spot-on, thank you for transparency on that. Another consideration: depending on the anticipate run-time of your software, consider if it's possible to self-throttle to "nmt one ping per day" or similar, though this will mask its use a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few considerations:

1. Just fetching a page with Google Analytics on it won't work because the actual analytics occurs as a result of some JavaScript which is loaded. You'll either need to run some very simple code on a server or use some service with a HTTP API. Sticking with using Google Analytics, there's the pretty simple to use [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide).
2. You'll need to make sure that the request isn't blocking, by using `async` or spawning another thread or through some other method.
3. In terms of actual implementation if you're using Python you can use the standard library `urllib.request.urlopen` to make the request without needing to worry about any dependencies, or alternatively choose to use the popular `requests` library.

Comment: Been trying to do this and I have to admit that I don;t quite get what you mean sorry.

I've created a little script to test this 
`import urllib.request`
`x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://URL_to_html_page.com')`
`print(x.read())`

When I call the page, it prints the html to the terminal, but doesn't register a hit on google analytics (it does if I open it in a browser). I assume that this is what you were warning me about. The next step I guess is to add some script to my html page? I've had a look at the GA Measurement Protocol but don't understand what's needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found this website which gives a very simple python script which achieves this - [link](https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/measure-your-python-projects-with-google-analytics/). All that's required in addition to the script is the the Google Analytics Property ID. No need to set up any code on my website, or even point the script at my website. This approach will trigger an 'event' rather than register as a page hit. I'll need to do some testing for stability and reliability of the analytics, but it's definitely on the right track. Thanks.